# Ленивая загрузка страницы

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, ajax, php, javascript

Привет.

Столкнулся с необходимостью выводить контент через ajax, плавно подгружая блоки в посадочной странице. Думал проверять размеры контента, и если скролл приближается к концу, то выводить через ajax запрос.

Сделал все через такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

var getHeightContent; sectionNumber = 0; loadPageAjax(sectionNumber); //загружаем первую часть

```
function loadPageAjax(getSectionNumbers) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "load.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {getSectionNumbers: getSectionNumbers},
        onSubmit: function ajaxViewsLoader() {
          //  пошел прелоадер,
        },
        success: function ajaxViewsSection(data) {
            // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим
            $("#lazyLoadContent").append(data);
            sectionNumber++;
            console.log(getHeightContent);
        }
    });
    getHeightContent = $("#lazyLoadContent").outerHeight();
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= getHeightContent - 5) {
        loadPageAjax(sectionNumber);
    };
});

});
```

В php просто массив и вывод:

```
$arraySelects = array(
0=>"
<section id='content-item-1' style='marging-bottom: 100px;'>
LINE #0: Просто какой-то текст? тест.<br/><br/>
</section>",
1=>"
<section id='content-item-1' style='marging-bottom: 100px;'>
LINE #1: Просто какой-то текст? тест.<br/>
LINE #1: Просто какой-то текст? тест.<br/>
</section>",
2=>"
<section id='content-item-2' style='marging-bottom: 100px;'>
LINE #2: Просто какой-то текст? тест.<br/>
</section>"
);

if(isset($_POST['getSectionNumbers'])){
    $getSectionNumber = $_POST['getSectionNumbers']; //сохраняем значение 
    echo "$arraySelects[$getSectionNumber]";
}
```

Выводит только первые два элемента массива, ошибок в консоли нет. В чем может быть проблема? Правильно ли я делаю? Есть ли уже рабочий велосипед?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function loadPageAjax(getSectionNumbers) {
$.ajax({
    url: "load.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {getSectionNumbers: getSectionNumbers},
    onSubmit: function ajaxViewsLoader() {
      //  пошел прелоадер,
    },
    success: function ajaxViewsSection(data) {
        // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим
        $("#lazyLoadContent").append(data);
        sectionNumber++;
        console.log(getHeightContent);
    }
});
getHeightContent = $("#lazyLoadContent").outerHeight();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 var getHeightContent = 0;sectionNumber = 0;

 loadPageAjax(sectionNumber);

$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log(getHeightContent)
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= getHeightContent - 5) {
        loadPageAjax(sectionNumber);
    };
});

});
```

в load.php:

```
0=>"<section id='content-item-0' style='marging-bottom: 100px;'>
```

У вас сейчас стоит "content-item-1"

Comment: Да, действительно, ошибка решилась. Примите мою благодарность.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант по мере скролла плавно открывать html канает? ) И никаких ajax. ))

Comment: Нет, просто вывод я знаю как сделать через плагин, но нужно именно подгружать для скорости загрузки страницы.